# kernel read_lock followed by write_lock gives soft lock up

Tags: c, linux, kernel, locking

In order to optimize clearing items from hash table, I have used read_lock followed by write_lock :

```
DEFINE_RWLOCK(ht_rwlock);

void Clear(void (*deleter)(const void*))
{
    int i;
    struct hash_table* temp_node;

    read_lock(&ht_rwlock);
    hash_for_each(spu_hash_table, i, temp_node, next)
    {
        write_lock(&ht_rwlock);
        hash_del(&temp_node->next);
        write_unlock(&ht_rwlock);

        deleter((const void*)temp_node);
    }
    read_unlock(&ht_rwlock);
}
```

However this gives me an error:
kernel:BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [rmmod:6724]

Non optimized version with write_lock/write_unlock only works OK:

```
void Clear(void (*deleter)(const void*))
{
    int i;
    struct hash_table* temp_node;

    write_lock(&ht_rwlock);
    hash_for_each(spu_hash_table, i, temp_node, next)
    {
        hash_del(&temp_node->next);
        deleter((const void*)temp_node);
    }
    write_unlock(&ht_rwlock);
}
```

My question is do I really have to use write lock to iterate over hash table ?

Comment: Might depend on just what `deleter` does.

Comment: For *delete* elements from the hash table, `hash_for_each_safe` macro should be used. Unlike to `hash_for_each` one, this macro is steady to removing elements.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is do I really have to use write lock to iterate over hash table?

Yes. RWlock in the kernel doesn't support transition from read lock to write lock.

Reason is simple: having two processes, each of them under read section and wanted to advance it to write one, leads to deadlock.

But your case is pure *modification* one (you delete all elements from the list), so using read_lock with transforming it to write lock wouldn't gain performance in any case. Use `write_lock`, as in your 2nd code.

---

If you care about perfomance, consider using RCU locks - it allows reader and writer to operate concurrently, so `rwlock` becomes not needed at all, simple `lock` for synchronize writers is sufficient. But appliance of RCU is depended from context.